How would I say "even", as in, "Do you even [verb]"?
For example, if you have a conversation that goes like: "I'm going to drive to the gym tomorrow." "Do you even have a car?"
How would the word "even" in this context be expressed in Latin? Or to give another example sentence: "Do you even know where you're going?"

Somewhat related: "Don't even..."

@Nomad1004: Joonas's link leads to "quidem", so "scisne quidem quo vadis,"--"Do you (not) indeed even know to where you are going?"; "quidem" is more emphatic than e.g. "etiam"--"scisne etiam quo vadis,"--"Do you (not) even know to where you are going?".

@tony, The problem is that quidem without ne in front of it works quite differently than ne...quidem; so I don't think you can have the 'not' in your translation bracketed as though it's somehow implied. Also, 'indeed' is one of those filler-type definitions that dictionaries give for various Latin particles when they don't know what else to do with them or don't have the space to deal with them properly. In short, I don't think quidem works at all in this context – without ne, at least, and possibly even with it.

@cnread That looks like a good answer to me. Want to post it as an answer? I don't think it even needs expansion.

@tony cnread is correct, also, the example sentences you gave are grammatically incorrect on top of that, since indirect questions take the subjunctive

@Nomad1004: Are you sure about this: "Do you even know where you are going?" sounds direct. To turn this into an indirect; "nescio quo eas," = "I don't know where you are going," where "eas" is present subjunctive.

@Joonas llmavirta: Could you comment on the direct/indirect question debate, please?

@tony You're wrong there. Your example is indirect without any ambiguity and requires the conjunctive. Maybe you should read on what an indirect question is grammatically, paying attention to the distinction between semantics and grammar.

@Joonas llmavirta: Thanks. A small revision: "scisne etiam quo vadas,".
